# jQuery replace with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays

i want to replace the content of the textarea with the list of my "replacements".
so that "Hi 23" is going to be "\u041D\u0456 23". whats my mistake?

```
$("textarea#comment").val(function(i, val) {
 return val.replace(/*the first letter (e.g. A)*/g, "*the second row e.g. \u0410*");
});

replacements = {
    "A": "\u0410",
    "B": "\u0412",
    "C": "\u0421",
    "H": "\u041D",
    "I": "\u0406",
    "J": "\u0408",
    "M": "\u041C",
    "O": "\u041E",
    "P": "\u0420",
    "S": "\u0405",
    "T": "\u0422",
    "V": "\u0474",
    "Y": "\u04AE",

    "a": "\u0430",
    "c": "\u0441",
    "e": "\u0435",
    "h": "\u04BB",
    "i": "\u0456",
    "j": "\u0458",
    "l": "\u04C0",
    "o": "\u043E",
    "p": "\u0440",
    "s": "\u0455",
    "y": "\u0443",
    "v": "\u0475";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var replacements = {
    "A": "\\u0410",
    "B": "\\u0412",
    "C": "\\u0421",
    "H": "\\u041D",
    "I": "\\u0406",
    "J": "\\u0408",
    "M": "\\u041C",
    "O": "\\u041E",
    "P": "\\u0420",
    "S": "\\u0405",
    "T": "\\u0422",
    "V": "\\u0474",
    "Y": "\\u04AE",

    "a": "\\u0430",
    "c": "\\u0441",
    "e": "\\u0435",
    "h": "\\u04BB",
    "i": "\\u0456",
    "j": "\\u0458",
    "l": "\\u04C0",
    "o": "\\u043E",
    "p": "\\u0440",
    "s": "\\u0455",
    "y": "\\u0443",
    "v": "\\u0475"
}

$("textarea#comment").val(function(i, val)
{
    val = val.split('');

    $.each(val, function(i,e){
        val[i] = replacements[e] ? replacements[e] : e;
    });

    return val.join('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6A2JG/