# How to replace letters with alt codes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace

Okay, so I want to make an HTML page with JavaScript. I want whatever I put in an input bar, to be translated differently. So for example if I put `a` in the box I want it to put `☺`. And if I type a word like `hello` I want it to show as `◘♣♀♀☼`. Would anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/FPsdy/3/

You will have to fill the replacements array with what you want characters you want to.

```
var replacements = {
    "A": ")",
    "B": ">",
    "C": "'",
}

$('input[value=Translate]').click(function(){
   $("#translator").val(function(i, val)
{
    val = val.split('');

    $.each(val, function(i,e){
        val[i] = replacements[e] ? replacements[e] : e;
    });

    return val.join('');
});
});
```

Source: [jQuery replace with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224127/jquery-replace-with-array)